# Converting arrays into another format (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

i want to convert this array

```
 Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [12] => Array
                (
                )
            [13] => Array
                (
                 [16] => Array
                    (
                    )
                )
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
        )
    [10] => Array
        (
        )
    [14] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

into this format

```
Array
(
    [2] => 2
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [13] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16
                )
        )

    [5] => 5
    [10] => 10
    [14] => 14
)
```

can anybody help? thanks.
**[continued 16Mar2010]**

its not

> [2] =>array

but

> [2] => 2

if it is an array with 1 child or more, then it would be `[4] => Array([12]=>12`

input data is

> $a = array(2 => array(), 4 => array(12
>   => array(), 13 => array(16 => array())), 5 => array(), 10 =>
>   array(), 14 => array());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function refactor($a){
  $result = array();
  foreach($a as $k => $v)
    $result[$k] = (is_array($v) && count($v) > 0) ? refactor($v) : $k;
  return $result;
}
```

$a = array(2 => array(), 4 => array(12 => array(), 13 => array()), 5 => array(), 10 => array(), 14 => array());
print_r($a);
$b = refactor($a);
print_r($b);

Sorry, didn't see that you wanted the internal array not to have the keys and values as the same.

EDIT: After you updated your question, I edited my function to do what you need:

```
function refactor($a, $rootNode = false){
  $result = array();
  foreach($a as $k => $v){
      if($rootNode){
          $result[$k] = (is_array($v) && count($v) > 0) ? refactor($v) : $k;
      }else{
          $result[] = (is_array($v) && count($v) > 0) ? refactor($v) : $k;      
      }
  }
  return $result;
}

$a = array(2 => array(), 4 => array(12 => array(), 13 => array(16 => array())), 5 => array(), 10 => array(), 14 => array());
print_r($a);
$b = refactor($a, true);
print_r($b);
```

Comment: hi psytronic, after revise there is something going wrong. it is [2]=> array but i want [2]=>2, 4=>array because 4 contain additional array. do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @apis17 Mine displays [2] => 2 when I print out the results, are you not getting that? And does your other comment mean you have fixed it all now?

Comment: yes yes.. already fixed. 1st count the array. if result less than 2 $result[$k] become $value, else $result[$k."_child"] = $k. sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 5):

```
foreach($ary as $k => $v)
  $result[$k] = $v ? array_keys($v) : $k;
```

untested

Comment: tested / verified... Works because an empty array is treated as false.  If the array has values, it will get `array_keys()` otherwise the key name.

Comment: thank you stereofrog, this works but i want to add more trees there. let see the updates. thanks for helping.

Comment: the data is $a = array(2 => array(), 4 => array(12 => array(), 13 => array(16 => array())), 5 => array(), 10 => array(), 14 => array());

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = array ( "2" => array ( ) , "4" => array ( "12" => array () , 13 => array () , ) , 5 => array () , 10=> array () , 14 => array() );

foreach ( $arr as $key => $val )
{
global $arr ;
if ( empty ( $val ) )
{
  unset($arr[$key]);
  $arr[$key]=$key;
}
}

print_r  ( $arr) ;

?>
```

Comment: pavon_cool.. nice tips. it is close but can i make 12 and 13 as value not array?