# PHP function generate UL LI

Tags: php, arrays, treeview

i'm referring this address for function olLiTree

[PHP function that creates a nested ul li?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753853/php-function-that-creates-a-nested-ul-li)

i have this array

> $tree =
>   array("A"=>array("B"=>array("C"=>"C","D"=>"D"),"E"=>array("F"=>"F","G"=>"G")));

but not able to use this function

```
function olLiTree($tree)
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($tree as $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            olLiTree($item);
        } else {
            echo '<li>', $item, '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

to generate

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B
    <ul>
      <li>C</li>
      <li>D</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>E
    <ul>
      <li>F
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <ul>
    <li>G</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

can anybody help me to fix this?
thanks..

Comment: you have to have another array for such a list.
in your array B item is nested in A item, but in list they are equal positions

Comment: if possible i want sample to convert into compatible array. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP function that creates a nested ul li?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753853/php-function-that-creates-a-nested-ul-li)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function olLiTree($tree) {
    $out = '<ul>';

    foreach($tree as $key => $value) {
        $out.= '<li>';

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $out.= $key . olLiTree($value);
        } else {
            $out.= $value;
        }

        $out.= '</li>';
    }

    $out.= '</ul>';

    return $out;
}
```

Always `return` the final output, don't `echo` it directly. You'll thank yourself one day when you find a situation where you *don't* want to `echo` it immediately. :)

You might want to change the array structure to this, as it's less redundant (works with above code):

```
$tree = array('A', 'B', 'C' => array('CA', 'CB'), 'D');
```

Comment: thank you deceze.. didn't work as expected. or maybe actual array need to be adjusted to another format. do you think so?

Comment: @apis17 ...come again? What's stopping you from writing your array like this?

Comment: deceze: the structure was generated by database query. have no idea to make it compatilbe to make output using ulLiTree function.

Comment: @apis17 Without seeing your query it's hard to answer, but the above code should work with either structure. As others have noted though, the array in your question and what you expect to get out of it doesn't match.

Comment: ok done! i've corrected sql query array structure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423682/converting-arrays-into-another-format-php as appreciation i mark this as answer. thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

By using something like this it should work (I did not test it, so hopefully I did not make any embarrassing mistakes):

```
function olLiTree($tree)
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($tree as $key => $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            echo '<li>', $key;
            olLiTree($item);
            echo '</li>';
        } else {
            echo '<li>', $item, '</li>'; // Or use $key here as well
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

If you want to exactly match the given example you need to modify the array, since it does not match the result. (But I suppose that is not the problem)

Comment: this also not work. the array is: $tree = array("A"=>array("B"=>array("C"=>"C","D"=>"D"),"E"=>array("F"=>"F","G"=>"G")));

Comment: What is not working? I now tried and it showed the tree, which is different compared to your example tree, but that is due to the wrong $tree value.

Comment: any idea to convert that $tree value? maybe another function.

Comment: The example output you gave is incorrect HTML, the final `<ul>G</ul>` part is directly in the main `<ul></ul>` part, which is not allowed. Therefore the function is not able to perfectly reproduce it, but the `$tree` you give you also generate the same answer, except the `<ul>G</ul>` part which is put in the `<ul>E</ul>` part.
But, it would really help if you tell what is wrong: You get an error? The tree you put into the function is not matching the output? You need other output?

Comment: veger: the HTML was generated for testing only. there are nothing wrong but just my array structure. the problem is solved. thank you all for suggestion :)